# Programmatically add IP(s) or domain(s) to Relay Restrictions in SMTP Virtual Server on IIS 6

Tags: c#, iis, smtp

I have been given a task to create an admin page to programmatically add IPs or domains to a SMTP Relay Restrictions using C#.  I spent some time researching this since yesterday and finally traced this down to a few posts on several website that use the System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntr class. Using the examples I found, I can add or deny IPs or domains under Connection control but not Relay Restrictions.  What would be the commands in C# to add IPs to the Relay Restrictions?  Below is a pic of the GUI in IIS for reference.-

[image]

Comment: I think you need much more information about what whitelist this is and where it's stored. Is this a whitelist of senders that are able to send using a particular SMTP server on a given host?

Comment: I found more info on what I was trying to ask so I re-worded my question based on the new info.  Hope someone can get me on the right track

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research trying to find the best way to access the relay restriction list in IIS, I came up with this class.  This works great for what we are trying to do so feel free to take the code and adapt it to your use.  My gift to StackOverflow devs for giving me great answers to my questions every day.

I found this solution to be the easiest and cleanest way to solve my problem.  I used it to insert and retrieve IPs and DNS entries in the Relay Restriction list in IIS but it can also be used to insert and retrieve entries in the Connection control in IIS also.

Note:  IIS does not allow a delete of one entry in the list so I had to delete all the entries and them add the entire list back.  I could not find a way to delete one entry only.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Text;
using Ucf.Smtp.Wcf.Entities;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Ucf.Smtp.Wcf.BusinessLogic
{

public static class IisIntegration
{
    private static object _oIpSecurity;
    private static Type _typeIpSecurityType;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets IP|Domain into SMTP Server
    /// This method is used to insert one IP or DNS entry into the Relay Restriction List in IIS
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sMetabasePath">IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1</param>
    /// <param name="sMethodName">Get|Put</param>
    /// <param name="sMethodArgument">IPSecurity|RelayIPList</param>
    /// <param name="sMember">IPGrant|IPDeny|DomainGrant|DomainDeny</param>
    /// <param name="item">IP|Domain</param>
    /// <param name="listCurrent">List of current IP(s)|Domain(s)</param>
    /// <param name="aListNew">List of new IP(s)|Domain(s)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Boolean SetIpSecurityPropertySingle(String sMetabasePath, String sMethodName, String sMethodArgument, String sMember, String item, out List<EntityIpDomain> listCurrent, out List<EntityIpDomain> aListNew)
    {
        aListNew = null;

        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(sMetabasePath);
        directoryEntry.RefreshCache();

        _oIpSecurity = directoryEntry.Invoke(sMethodName, new[] { sMethodArgument });
        _typeIpSecurityType = _oIpSecurity.GetType();

        //retrieve array of IP(s)|Domain(s)
        Array aDataCurrent = GetIpSecurityData(_oIpSecurity, _typeIpSecurityType, sMember);

        //log entry
        Boolean bExists = ListIpDomainAndCheckIfNewExists(aDataCurrent, item);

        //convert array to list
        listCurrent = ConvertArrayToList(aDataCurrent);

        if (!bExists)
        {
            //instantiate new instance of object dataCurrent
            Object[] oNewData = new object[aDataCurrent.Length + 1];

            //copy dataCurrent into newData
            aDataCurrent.CopyTo(oNewData, 0);

            //add the new value to the newData object
            oNewData.SetValue(item, aDataCurrent.Length);

            //invokes the specified sMember using the arguments supplied
            _typeIpSecurityType.InvokeMember(sMember, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, _oIpSecurity, new object[] { oNewData });

            //invokes the arguments of the method
            directoryEntry.Invoke("Put", new[] { sMethodArgument, _oIpSecurity });

            //commits the changes
            directoryEntry.CommitChanges();

            //refreshes the cache
            directoryEntry.RefreshCache();

            //return the new list of IP(s)|Domain(s)
            _oIpSecurity = directoryEntry.Invoke("Get", new[] { sMethodArgument });
            Array aDataNew = (Array)_typeIpSecurityType.InvokeMember(sMember, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, _oIpSecurity, null);

            //log entry
            bExists = ListIpDomainAndCheckIfNewExists(aDataNew, item);

            aListNew = ConvertArrayToList(aDataNew);
        }

        return bExists;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set IP(s)|Domain(s) into SMTP Server
    /// This method is used to insert multiple IPs or DNS entries into the Relay Restriction List in IIS
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sMetabasePath">IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1</param>
    /// <param name="sMethodName">Get|Put</param>
    /// <param name="sMethodArgument">IPSecurity|RelayIPList</param>
    /// <param name="sMember">IPGrant|IPDeny|DomainGrant|DomainDeny</param>
    /// <param name="list">List of IP(s)\Domain(s)</param>
    public static Boolean SetIpSecurityPropertyArray(String sMetabasePath, String sMethodName, String sMethodArgument, String sMember, List<EntityIpDomain> list)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(sMetabasePath);

            directoryEntry.RefreshCache();

            //return result of Invoke method
            _oIpSecurity = directoryEntry.Invoke(sMethodName, new[] { sMethodArgument });

            //get Type of ipSecurity
            Type typeIpSecurityType = _oIpSecurity.GetType();

            Object[] newList = new object[list.Count];

            Int32 iCounter = 0;
            foreach (EntityIpDomain item in list)
            {
                newList[iCounter] = item.IpDomain;
                iCounter++;
            }

            // add the updated list back to the IPSecurity object
            typeIpSecurityType.InvokeMember(sMember, BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, _oIpSecurity, new object[] { newList });

            directoryEntry.Properties[sMethodArgument][0] = _oIpSecurity;

            // commit the changes
            directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
            directoryEntry.RefreshCache();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the IP(s)|Domain(s) from the SMTP Server in an Array
    /// This method retrieves teh IPs/DNS entries from the Relay Restriction List in IIS
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sMetabasePath">IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1</param>
    /// <param name="sMethodName">Get|Put</param>
    /// <param name="sMethodArgument">IPSecurity|RelayIPList</param>
    /// <param name="sMember">IPGrant|IPDeny|DomainGrant|DomainDeny</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<EntityIpDomain> GetIpSecurityPropertyArray(String sMetabasePath, String sMethodName, String sMethodArgument, String sMember)
    {
        //instantiates an instance of DirectoryEntry
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(sMetabasePath);
        directoryEntry.RefreshCache();

        //return result of Invoke method
        object oIpSecurity = directoryEntry.Invoke(sMethodName, new[] { sMethodArgument });

        //get Type of ipSecurity
        Type typeIpSecurityType = oIpSecurity.GetType();

        //returns an array of IPS or Domains
        Array data = GetIpSecurityData(oIpSecurity, typeIpSecurityType, sMember);

        //load the array into a generic list
        List<EntityIpDomain> list = new List<EntityIpDomain>();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            EntityIpDomain entityIpDomain = new EntityIpDomain();
            entityIpDomain.IpDomain = data.GetValue(i).ToString();
            list.Add(entityIpDomain);
        }

        return list;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a list of IPs or Domains
    /// //This is a helper method that actually returns an array of IPs/DNS entries from the Relay Restricton List in IIS
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oIpSecurity">Result of directoryEntry.Invoke</param>
    /// <param name="tIpSecurityType">Type of oIpSecurity</param>
    /// <param name="sMember">IPGrant|IPDeny|DomainGrant|DomainDeny</param>
    /// <returns>Array of IP(s)|Domain(s)</returns>
    private static Array GetIpSecurityData(object oIpSecurity, Type tIpSecurityType, String sMember)
    {
        return (Array)tIpSecurityType.InvokeMember(sMember, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oIpSecurity, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lists the IP(s)|Domain(s)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aData">Array of IP(s)|Domain(s)</param>
    /// <param name="sItem"></param>
    /// <returns>Stringbuilder of the list</returns>
    private static Boolean ListIpDomainAndCheckIfNewExists(Array aData, String sItem)
    {
        Boolean bExists = false;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (object oDataItem in aData)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(oDataItem + Environment.NewLine);
            if (oDataItem.ToString().StartsWith(sItem))
            {
                bExists = true;
            }
        }

        return bExists;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an array to a Genreic List of Type EntityIpDomain
    /// This method converts the array to a list so I can pass it back in a WCF service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aData">Array of IP(s)|Domain(s)</param>
    /// <returns>Generic List of Type EntityIpDomain</returns>
    private static List<EntityIpDomain> ConvertArrayToList(Array aData)
    {
        List<EntityIpDomain> list = new List<EntityIpDomain>(aData.Length);
        foreach (String item in aData)
        {
            EntityIpDomain ipDomainValue = new EntityIpDomain { IpDomain = item };
            list.Add(ipDomainValue);
        }

        return list;
    }
}

}


using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Ucf.Smtp.Wcf.Entities
{

[DataContract]
public class EntityIpDomain
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the value of the IP|Domain in a String
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public String IpDomain { get; set; }
}

}
```